# How to use JPA as a backup for Elastic Using spring data?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

If I have to design a GET API on elastic search, such that if data is not yet present in Elastic, then it should query the backing DB and see if the record is present there.

Main reason why we need to think of this is because there is a delay of some seconds between DB and Elastic and the GET call will be invoked way too many times to have it directly hit DB.

Any ideas? I'm using spring-data-elasticsearch right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Elastic for search then keep it as Elastic only. I would suggest thay if the data is not present then reindex(delete the specific data from Elastic if present and then save it again from Database (Jpa)). Your Elastic need to be consistent with the Jpa. Anyway, of you still wanna go ahead with it, then create a if condition for null and if it comes then search by JPA repository.